# Coldfusion 9 cflayout tabs

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm porting an existing CF8 web app over to CF9 on a development server and am having trouble getting cflayout tabs to work properly.  Firebug shows all the .js and .css files loading properly... no JS errors.  The tabs work when clicked on, but they are displaying the "name" property instead of the "title" property.  All tabs are closable (even though i specify false). Even though I have the first tabbed marked as selected, it isn't selected by default and nothing inside the cflayoutarea tag is displayed (content).  Has anyone else seen anything like this in ColdFusion 9?

Comment: Should take this over to http://StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from ColdFusion jumping from ExtJS 1 to ExtJS 3.  If the problems don't get fixed by release and you don't care about using the latest ExtJS libraries then you can use cfajaximport to run on the old files.  I've blogged about it here:

http://samfarmer.instantspot.com/blog/2009/08/14/Use-cfajaximport-to-help-with-CF8-to-CF9-migration

Answer (score 0):

file the bug at : http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

If you do a search on cflayout or any other cfajax output tags, you'll see a lot of bugs in the bug tracker.  Hopefully they will be ironed out by the time CF9 is released.